# How to speed up google chart loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization

I have this problem, I hope it is not too especific:  I take some data from different servers (the amount of the servers would vary, but in my test case there are 10 servers besides my localhost) to create the charts. They work absolutely fine, but they are too slow for my taste (the column and bar chart take about 5 seconds while the geo chart takes around 10 seconds)

This is the ajax call used to get the data from the servers:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: [server's php page where i get i data'],
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            [some data]
        },
        success: function(data) {
            (JSON.parse(data || "null") != null) ? [function for success case] : false;
        },
        error: function() {
            [function for error case]
        }
  });
```

Code used to create the charts once I have all the needed data:

```
var options = {
            title: title,
            hAxis: {title: axis_title, titleTextStyle: {color: '#F0F0F0'}, baselineColor: '#F0F0F0', textStyle: {color: '#F0F0F0'}},
            vAxis: {titleTextStyle: {color: '#F0F0F0'}, baselineColor: '#F0F0F0', textStyle: {color: '#F0F0F0'}},
            legend: {textStyle: {color: '#F0F0F0'}},
            titleTextStyle: {color: '#F0F0F0', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '13px', bold: false},
            fontSize: 12,
            backgroundColor: {fill: 'transparent'},
            colors: ['#04c']
        };
chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

Basically my question is this: are the charts generated slowly because of a google chart api/ajax/etc or is this caused by a mistake I'm doing?

Thanks!

Comment: It's more likely because of a problem in your code.  How long does a regular AJAX request take (without the charts).  For example, try pointing your browser to `url: [server's php page where i get i data'],` and see how long it takes.

Comment: A single ajax request is pretty fast itself, with the charts it takes 1 or 2 seconds, max, and without them it takes even less, mostly 1 second or less.

Comment: The ajax call to all the servers takes way more, since each ajax is making a async call, each ajax call ends up calling the function in charge of creating the graphs

Comment: Just open up google chrome and click f12.  Look at the Network tab and refresh the page.  You will see what calls are taking longer than they should.

Comment: the calls are done immediately, a second or less for all the calls

Comment: Are you using your AJAX + google charts like this?  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

Comment: Normally, the Visualization API can draw charts quite fast (millisecond time scales).  GeoCharts can take a bit longer if the API has to geocode data points.  Unless you have a geocoding issue, it is likely the AJAX requests that are taking a long time, open the network tab in the Chrome developer tools and refresh the page to see how long each request is taking to complete.

Comment: user1477388 no, i don't, they are used exaclty like it's described in my question. But I gonna try it, maybe it runs faster. asgallant the column charts are loading much faster now, 209ms the fastest and 1.11s the slowest, and the geo chart is still very slow: the fastest 1.12s and the slowest 11.23s

Comment: @user1477388 I tried to create the ajax call like you said, but with the async as false it takes way longer (15 seconds or more) and without it (async as true) it takes the same time. I checked in the dev tools and the ajax calls are fast (the geo chart is an exception), there must to be some flaw in my logic between the ajax call and the chart draw (the logic in charge of sum the results of every call)

Comment: So you're saying it's fast if you load the AJAX source directly, but it's slow when you try to use the exact same AJAX source as the data source for your Google Chart?

Comment: Yes, but now im pretty sure the error is more related to something server side (it can be either the sql call or the php geoip functions) I checked the same code againt different servers and there the ajax calls and the chart draw are quick (less than a second for bars and columns, 1.5 for geo), now the only one giving trouble is my localhost. So basically the question is now out of place since it's tecnically working the way intended.